# An unexpected behavior of strcpy_s in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-c++

Platform: Win11, VisualStudio 2022
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char ori[5] = { 'a', 'b', '\0', 'c', 'd' };
    //char *safe = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    //char *unsafe = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

    char safe[10];
    char unsafe[10];
    memset(safe, 0, 10 * sizeof(char));
    memset(unsafe, 0, 10 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(unsafe, ori);
    strcpy_s(safe, 10, ori);
    printf("SAFE: %c\n", safe[3]);
    printf("UnSafe: %c\n", unsafe[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I have two arrays, `safe` and `unsafe`. After `memset`, both of them are initialized as `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` (showing characters as integers).

After `strcpy` and `strcpy_s`, I expect to get `{'a','b','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'}` in both the `safe` and `unsafe` arrays. However, in `safe`, I obtained `{97,98,0,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2}` (showing characters as integers).

What does `strcpy_s` do, and where does the `-2` come from?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. It's better to write `memset(safe, 0, sizeof safe);` because you don't need to change the size anymore when `safe` is changed

Comment: This looks like C, not C++. Why would you use C-style arrays, `malloc` & `strcpy` in C++? `printf` and `memset` I could in some cases tolerate, but there'd have to be a *really good* reason (here there's not).

Comment: FYI: [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: @JesperJuhl, The code is in C, and I used wrong tags.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Done, with c and visual-c++, cause not find "visual-c" tag

Comment: @ZhouJia: The tag `visual-c++` is correct, as that is the name of the product. [Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) supports both C and C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official Microsoft documentation for the function `strcpy_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-170) states the following:

> The debug library versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFE. To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold.

If you convert `0xFE` to a `signed char`, you get the value `-2`.

Comment: [It's one of the useful debug values in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/995714): 0xFE *Used to fill slack space in some memory buffers  (unused parts of `std::string` or the user buffer passed to `fread()`)*

Answer (score 3):

Writing `-2` is allowed by the C specification.

```
errno_t strcpy_s(char * restrict s1, rsize_t s1max, const char * restrict s2);
```

> All elements following the terminating null character (if any) written by `strcpy_s` in the array of `s1max` characters pointed to by `s1` take unspecified values when `strcpy_s` returns.  C17dr § K.3.7.1.3 4

This applies **regardless of any debug setting** or compiler used.
Code should not rely on bytes past the *null character* to remain unchanged.

Comment: Visual Studio does not follow C11 Annex K "bounds checking interface". Nor does it follow C11. Nor does it follow standard C.

Comment: @Lundin Even if MS claim [Support for C11 and C17 standards is available in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and later.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/install-c17-support?view=msvc-170) is true, weak or false, OP can still code to current C standard.  In this case, code should not rely on the value of bytes past the null character to be anything particular.

Comment: MS are shamelessly lying. Try the actual compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/zdWxPjKGz.

Comment: @Lundin Interestingly `/std:c11  /Zc:__STDC__` and `/std:c17  /Zc:__STDC__` compile.  `/std:c99  /Zc:__STDC__`, as expected, does not.